# Need to fetch data from token-based API

Tags: c#, json, ssis, webapi

I'm new to C# coding, 
I need to fetch data through the SSIS package using a script component task from api which has many filter api URL inside it. 
The main login URL is similar to http://URL:portname/user/signin.
By using the loginid and password, I need to generate the token and then I need to pass the token in the filter api header whose url is similar to http://URL:portname/division.

Comment: Are you developing the client application, the server application or both?

Comment: hello sorry for the late reply, actually the APIs has already been developed, I just need to fetch the data from them using SSIS, Kindly help.

Comment: Thanks you for your reply ,